# TextBox GUI programming in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, textbox

I am trying to learn GUI programming in C# and I have the following question regarding the default code the for TextBox in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication34
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         // Textbox programming goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I want to try something a bit different with the TexBox programming something similar to this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication20
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //
        // Detect the KeyEventArg's key enumerated constant.
        //
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed enter! Good job!");
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed escape! What's wrong?");
        }
    }
    }
}
```

I can't run the code and because of the status of the TextBox is

```
textBox1_KeyDown
```

and not the default one which is

```
textBox1_TextChanged
```

Now my question is, how do I go about changing the TextBox event handler from the default one to another?

Comment: What are you talking about? What error do you get?

Comment: I can't run the code and because of the status of the textbox is?What does this mean?What actually you want to do?

Comment: Just a hunch, but maybe you double clicked the textbox in the visual studio designer. This created a default `TextChanged` event. To register other events for the textbox, use the 'events' pane of the properties panel, and double-click on the event you want to create.

Comment: Whats the status of the textbox? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Click the lightning bolt icon in the Properties window.  Double-click KeyDown.

Comment: thanks hans, it was exaxtly what i wanted to do :)

Answer (score 6):

`KeyDown` and `TextChanged` are different **events**.

Instead of double clicking the textbox to enter code the event, select the events tab in the properties and double click the event you want to write code for.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to look for is the OnPreviewKeyDown event... it tells you what is coming next.  If you want to bypass it's activity, you set the "Handled" property to true.

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
   var ue = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;

   if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
   { 
      MessageBox.Show("You pressed enter! Good job!");
      e.Handled = true;   // to tell event stack you've already taken care of this condition
   }
   else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
      MessageBox.Show("You pressed escape! What's wrong?");
}
```